# How to determine the version of pg_agent installed?

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

How do I determine the version of pg_agent installed?

Is it queriable with SQL just like checking PostgreSQL version / PostGIS version ?

Comment: I have never used pgAgent, but according [to the manual](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/pgagent_install.html) it's installed as an extension. So at least the version of the extension should be visible in `pg_extension` (which might not necessarily be the same as the version of the Linux daemon you also need to install)

Answer (score 1):

You can query pg_catalog.pg_extension to get information about installed extensions.

```
SELECT extversion FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension WHERE  extname = 'pgagent'
```

Best regards, Tim